# C lang basic issue - why did I get the same addresses to two struct?

Tags: c

```
while (1) 
{
    struct entry n =
    {
        ele[i], NULL, 1
    };
    printf("%d", &n); // todo the same address
}
```

This program keeps printing the same address, isn't the struct entry n = xxx an operation like "new" in c++ and java? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not at all the same. Here you are creating a struct that will be already allocated space compile-time and will have the same address all the time. There is no need to create a new one ever. You are just setting the values inside the struct.

The value is allocated in the stack and since you are in the same stack frame, it will stay the same.

If you would change the code into calling a function, the value would change. For example

```
void test1()
{
    struct entry n =
    {
        ele[i], NULL, 1
    };
    printf("%d", &n);
}

void test2()
{
    test1();
}

void main()
{
    test1();
    test1();
    test2();
    test1();
    test2();
}
```

From the first two you will (most likely) get the same address, since there is exactly the same stack modifications in the calls. But when you call `test2()`, which calls `test1()` then the address is different, since the stack frame is different.

But even in this case the address of the struct *must not* be stored anywhere, since it is just a temporary local variable, which will disappear after returning from the function and dereferencing it would invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, so the n is just a constant address local variable. Itself does not change when looping. But how do i keep allocating new structs in the loop body? Should i use malloc?

Comment: @macomgil It depends on what you do with the structs. If you need to store them somewhere, you need to dynamically allocate new ones when you need them.

Comment: Or make an array of them at a higher scope one time and use them until not needed.  This avoids malloc/new fun and lets the compiler clean up the stack for you as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> isn't the struct entry n = xxx an operation like "new" in c++ and java?

Can't say anything about java since I am not familiar with the language.

It's certainly not like `new` in C++.

`n` is an automatic variable and its address, `&n`, is the same in every iteration of 
the `while` loop.